# How to workaround average function in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, average

I've taken an online excel course and stuck at one of the exercise for average function.

In the image, the average function is showing error div/0

Note that TAX column values have been calculated by formula. Is that the reason for this error? I tried searching online but could not get any proper answers... can anyone please help? Thank you.

Formula applied in tax column  =IF(AND(C2 < 100), "50","100")

[image]

Comment: Column D contains *text*, not numbers. Change `=IF(AND(C2 < 100), "50","100")` to `IF(C2<100,50,100)`. Once you enclose `50` and `100` in `"`, they are text, not numbers.

Comment: @BigBen Further to BigBen's great catch;  It gets confusing because there are many cases where Excel recognizes our intentions, and re-casts the text into a number value for us.  This lulls us into being undisciplined about it.  If cells D2:D9 each contained the formula `="50"` the `=average(D2:D9)` would return 50.  But if D2:D9 each contained the formula `=IF(TRUE,"50")` then the average function returns `#DIV/0`.  Such are the vagaries of Excel type-casting.  Excel's mystery logic takes into account *how* the text value ended up in D2, not just that it is text.